# Why does Ad Hoc build a different version of a Xamarin app than Visual Studio on Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Here is the landing page for my application:

```
<ContentView x:Class="ThetaRex.OpenBook.Quant.Forms.Views.MainView"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ThetaRex.OpenBook.Quant.Forms.Controls"
             x:DataType="viewModels:MainViewModel"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ThetaRex.OpenBook.Quant.Common.ViewModels;assembly=ThetaRex.OpenBook.Quant.Common"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label FontSize="Large"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               Margin="20,40,20,10"
               Text="{x:Binding WelcomeLabel}"/>
        <StackLayout Margin="20,0">
            <ListView HasUnevenRows="True"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Binding Items}"
                      Margin="20,0">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:FunctionItemViewModel">
                        <ViewCell>
                            <controls:DetailButton Command="{x:Binding Command}"
                                                   CommandParameter="{x:Binding CommandParameter}"
                                                   Description="{x:Binding Description}"
                                                   IsEnabled="{x:Binding IsEnabled}"
                                                   Label="{x:Binding Label}"/>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

This is what it looks like when built on a Mac and built on Windows:

[image]

I built both using the *exact* same code and Visual Studio (Mac/Windows), then Archive to file, then load IPA using iTunes.

At no point did I ask for a scrollable window for the main stack layout, but the VS Windows seems to add that capability. Does anyone have a clue what's going on here?

Comment: Could you please help confirm if you are installed the package in the same machine?And what xamarin.forms you are using?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT - Not really sure what you're asking. Both machines have the latest NuGet packages. In fact, I pulled the exact same repo from GitHub on both machines. The only difference is that the one on the left was produced on a Mac and published through TestFlight, the one on the right was built on a Windows machine and installed by dragging a signed IPA file into iTunes.

Comment: Looks like it's caused by platform specification as the code is the same.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT - Yeah, I'm starting to believe that this is a known problem with a ListView inside a StackPanel. The real issue isn't why it's broken. I'm starting to think that the issue here is why it ever works when I build on the Mac.